# Oculus Integration OnClick() Event on UI Button - Unity with Hand Tracking

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I have a UI button in Unity, and to create it I used the `PokeInteractable` prefab already prepared in the SDK samples.

Now, I need to detect the click on it, to trigger some events (exactly as a OnClick() event in a traditional Unity Button). However, I am not finding any script/way to do so. Even the SDK documentation has no indication about it.

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add a InteractableUnityEventWrapper component on the same game object that implements the PokeInteractable. The WhenSelect() callback is the equivalent of a button OnClick(). The InteractableView field requires to be set to the same game object, the PokeInteractable component implements IInteractableView for that matters.